# Help with simple RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to use a simple htaccess rule to have neat URLs, like so.

```
http://domain.com/theid => read by http://domain.com/read.php?id=theid
```

but still have other urls like just http://domain.com read normally

after playing around I ended up with this (not working):

```
RewriteRule ^domain.com\/(.){5}$ read.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriterules shouldn't include the domain, so you need to write something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.{5})$ /read.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, although it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: no, but modifying it a bit got it going: ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})$ read.php?id=$1